# How target only WooCommerce single product pages with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, html-table, product

When I add `tr { display: inline-grid; }` it causes issues in cart page and other pages. How to apply it only in product page?

I need to put the variations under the attribute name. Please see the following screenshots:

##### Screenshot 1:

[image]

##### Screenshot 2:

[image]

I also need to reduce the space between variations if the product has 2 variations:

```
tr { display: inline-grid; }
```

Comment: To help you to reduce the space between those 2 dropdowns, please provide a website related link to a product page with 2 dropdowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target single product pages, use the body class: `single-product`.

To target the attribute dropdowns table for variable products, use: `table.variations`

All together:

```css
.single-product table.variations tr { display: inline-grid; }
```

It should work as desired.

Comment: thanks a lot. the first one worked perfectly. the second one didn't make any changes. the space is big and couldn't be reduced the same as in Image 2

Comment: Thanks a lot, Loic, this is my first time using Stackoverflow so I didn't know that I could accept answers. here is a link https://www.pmvision.ca/shop/oracle-primavera-p6-training-course-primavera-p6-professional-quebec/